# Custom image size without stretching using Intervation Image?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a thumb from an orginal image with size 263x385, the problem is that the image always stretches. Any suggestion on how I can accomplish this?

I'm currently using this code:

```
$image->resize(263, 385, function ($c) {
    $c->upsize();
})->save($article_image_path . '/article_' . $article->id . '/thumbs/263x385/' . $filename);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`fit()`](https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/fit) method.

> Combine cropping and resizing to format image in a smart way. The method will find the best fitting aspect ratio of your given width and height on the current image automatically, cut it out and resize it to the given dimension.

Comment: when i use fit method if i have some image for example cat ... i get only her eye for this dimension

Comment: Are you sure you're doing everything right? Sounds like `fit()` just crops your image without resizing.

Comment: im sure, im using   $image->fit(263, 385)